# Gridview itemTemplate control enable/disable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

here is my code in asp.net... when it renders the code i have a `[checkbox]` with `[dropdownlist]` by default all the dropdownlist disabled when the page loads by doing like this:

```
var $ddls = $('select');
$ddls.prop("disabled", true);
```

**my question** is: how to enabled the dropdown only when the checkbox is checked? and if the checkbox is unchecked then disabled the dropdown

```
<asp:GridView ID="routePlanGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 

    <Columns>          
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <div class="selectreason">
                <asp:CheckBox CssClass="selectme" ID="chkReject" runat="server" Checked="false">
                </asp:CheckBox>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="detail" >
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select me</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">one</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">two</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">three</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">four</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the `RowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var chk = e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null)
    {
        var ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {
            //assign the JavaScript function to execute when the checkbox is clicked               
            //pass in the checkbox element and the client id of the select
            chk.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("toggleSelectList(this, '{0}');", ddl.ClientID);
        }
    }
}
```

The `toggleSelectList` function would look something like this:

```
toggleSelectList = function(el, selectID){
    var selectElement = document.getElementById(selectID);
    if (selectElement){
        selectElement.disabled = !el.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `toggleSelectList` looks like

Comment: @AbuHamzah: Updated my answer. Something like that should work.

Comment: @AbuHamzah: There was a typo in my JavaScript function: the argument was called `select` instead of `selectID`. Updated my answer with the correct syntax.

Comment: 1+ get back to you...after i test it.

Comment: i have a new question similar to what you have answered, see if you can help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521612/select-only-one-checkbox-for-a-given-row-in-mulitple-selection-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure, but I think you can use `JQuery` [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) or [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to the `check-box`.

```
$('.selectme').change(function() {  
  var ddl = $(this).siblings("input[type='select']");

  if ($('this').is(':checked'))
  {
       $('ddl').attr('disabled', false);
  }
  else
  {
       $('ddl').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks but i am using asp.net controls which works different with jquery then plain html controls works but 1+

Comment: @AbuHamzah: It doesn't matter if you use asp.net controls. Jquery works fine !!

Comment: @I haven't try this specific situation. But I had used it before for similar kind of client side purposes