# Select only one checkbox for a given row in mulitple selection - jQuery

Tags: asp.net

in the below gridview i have two checkboxs 
1) approve and 2) reject 
**my question is:** how can i restrict the user to select only one checkbox for a given row which is approve or reject? NOT both.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="routePlanGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >        
            <Columns>          
             <HeaderTemplate>[Select All]<br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApproveAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectAll(this, '.selectapprove'); " />
            </HeaderTemplate>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="approve">
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <div class="selectreason">
                        <asp:CheckBox CssClass="selectme" ID="chkapprove" runat="server" Checked="false">
                        </asp:CheckBox>
                     </div>
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="reject">
 <HeaderTemplate>[Select All]<br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRejectAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectAll(this, '.selectreject'); " />
            </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <div class="selectreason">
                        <asp:CheckBox CssClass="selectme" ID="chkreject" runat="server" Checked="false">
                        </asp:CheckBox>
                     </div>
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using CheckBoxes and not RadioButtons?

Comment: the reason i am using is that, in the header i have a checkbox (which i did not post the code) for both columns (approve/reject) so user can select all or de-select all and thats the reason using the checkbox... make sense?

Comment: i updated my question with checkbox in the headertemplate of an gridview

Answer (score 1):

If I understand how your form works you should be using Radio Buttons. They work exactly the way you want already. Also it will be more intuitive to your users.

[Edit]

Radio buttons have an extra attribute called "name" is used to put them into groups

Comment: i updated my question and also read my comments to James Johnson

Comment: I see. I understand your situation better now. I would go with buttons that update their appearance to reflect that the conditions imposed by their action is still true. I maintain that the behavior you are trying to achieve confusing because checkboxes explicitly can be checked or unchecked independently. lastly, this is all personal preference. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use radio button instead of checkbox. In code behind on item created event find the radio button object and set different groupname per row. This will allow you to choose options per row not per column.

Answer (score 0):

**<kbd>Mark Up</kbd>**

```
<asp:GridView ID="routePlanGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <headertemplate>[Select All]<br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApproveAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectAll(this, '.selectapprove'); " />
            </headertemplate>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="approve">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="selectreason">
                    <asp:CheckBox CssClass="selectme" onclick="return SelectSingle(this);" ID="chkapprove" runat="server" Checked="false">
                    </asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="reject">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                [Select All]<br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRejectAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectAll(this, '.selectreject'); " />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="selectreason">
                    <asp:CheckBox CssClass="selectme" ID="chkreject" runat="server" onclick="return SelectSingle(this);" Checked="false">
                    </asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

**<kbd>JavaScript</kbd>**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SelectSingle(CtlId) {
        debugger;
        var chkreject, chkapprove;
        if (CtlId.id.indexOf('chkreject') > -1) {
            chkreject = document.getElementById(CtlId.id).checked;
            chkapprove = document.getElementById(CtlId.id.replace('chkreject', 'chkapprove')).checked;
        }
        else if (CtlId.id.indexOf('chkapprove') > -1) {
            chkapprove = document.getElementById(CtlId.id).checked;
            chkreject = document.getElementById(CtlId.id.replace('chkapprove', 'chkreject')).checked;
        }
        if (chkapprove == true && chkreject == true)
            alert('both checked');
        else
            alert('both not checked');
    }
 </script>
```